# Working with vim on multiple monitors

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

I have three monitors.

I normally run one maximized xterm on each monitor, attached to the same [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session.

Can a similar model be used for vim? Is it possible to have three vims running, all sharing the same "vim session":

- Each vim window showing a different vim tab
- vim settings shared between all windows
- Not getting the "Swap file ... already exists!" error message if I open the same file on two tabs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have a working solution where two vim instances communicate.

http://github.com/codeape2/vim-multiple-monitors

It uses the SwapExists autocmd to instruct the other instance to open a file if an existing swap file is detected.

Comment: I tried to use your vim script, but I don't get how you supposed vim to understand the `--servername` argument. My vim (7.3) simply dies with the error message `Unknown option argument: "--servername"`. What did I miss?

Comment: Perhaps your vim is not compiled with support for remote invokation. In vim, execute ``:version``. Check if features includes ``+clientserver``

Comment: In Ubuntu, I had to install vim-gnome to get a vim with +clientserver support.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `vim` under `screen`.

```
$ screen
$ vim

# on another terminal 
$ screen -x
# the same vim screen
```

If your terminal emulator supports tabbing (e.g. gnome-terminal), you can use it as a tabbing (IMHO, gnome-terminals' tabbing support is better than vim's own, except perhaps you can't copy and paste among different vim sessions, however you can instead use the system copy-paste buffer: "+y and "+p).

This does not work if you're using gvim though.

Comment: Won't this simply mirror what's happening?

Comment: I would think so ....

Answer (score 3):

No, a Vim instance is limited to a single application window on your desktop.  The different Vim instances have independent sessions.

In addition, be aware that if you open the same file in two different Vim instances, not only do you get the 'Swap file exists' message, but the two instances do not share a buffer, so changes made in one are independent of the other.

If a changed file is saved in one instance you will get a message when you return to the file in another Vim instance that 'the file has changed since editing started' and asking you if you want to reload the file (which would load changes as saved by the other instance, disregarding any changes you had made in the current instance).

Answer (score 2):

[Neovim](https://salt.bountysource.com/teams/neovim) is a project that aim to give vim attach/detach feature like tmux.
This feature isn't yet implemented (june 19th 2015), but this may come soon.

There is many other core features for this project that you can see at neovim.io.

Comment: I think as of November 2017 this is still unimplemented and not being worked on

Answer (score 1):

:set noswapfile
:set autoread

Buffers aren't shared this way but vim reads file changes automatically if you save it. And you don't get that 'Swap file exists' message.